# GetSystemTime() wHour not providing correct value MFC C++

Tags: c++, time, mfc

I am trying to get the system time from the computer and for some reason i can't get the correct value printed.

My Code :

```
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    CString mill;
    mill.Format("%02d:%02d:%02d,%03d", st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
    MessageBox(mill);
```

Output :

```
02:01:02,692
```

I ran this function when it is 10.01a.m.

I do not understand why st.wHour is giving me 02 instead. Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The SYSTEMTIME being returned probably has a timezone of UTC.  That is, 8 hours off if you are in California.  Try GetLocalTime() instead.

Comment: Ahh! Thats it! Gah, to fail for such a thing :( Thanks so much!

Comment: I suspect 8 hours east. (Note [decimal mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma) ',')   Maybe [Indonesia Central Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B08:00)?